# Determine the date time a feature was installed on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have another department logging onto a server without authorization. I want to determine if they added a feature without following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Event Viewer for this.  Open Event Viewer, then expand Windows Logs, and click on Setup.

You'll want to create a filter that looks for these keywords:  **Microsoft-Windows-ServerManager** or just **ServerManager** or **Event IDs 1611 & 1610.**  Preferably filtering for the event IDs.

```
For Roles, look for event ID 1611

For Features, look for event ID 1610
```

Example of Features added screenshot in the Event Viewer on my lab server:

[image]

[See here as well.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4a324c67-7972-49dd-aa36-44867bee11d1/is-there-a-way-to-determine-when-a-role-was-added-to-a-windows-server?forum=winservergen)

Comment: Is this valid for features too?

Comment: Yes, see my answer edits.  Look for Event ID 1610 (Features) instead of 1611 (Roles)

Comment: Were you able to try it yet @MVCylon ?

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad to hear it.